# External hard drive spinning down too early

Tags: ubuntu, external-hard-drive, power-management

I have a Mac Mini 2007 running Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS with an external Hitachi Touro Mobile 3.0 attached. APM is 127 (hdparm -B127) with standby value of 1 hour (hdparm -B242).

But the disk is spinning down too early and doesn't matter if the standby value is 1 hour or 5 hours. If I run something like "du" or "tree", the disk goes to standby seconds after the command ends. (checked it with smartctl -n standby)

Is there anything I can do to make the disk respect the standby time or it's better to disable spindown to prevent early wearing of the disk?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happening if there's an issue with providing enough power. As per the standard, USB 3 is supposed to handle 900mA, but I have found hardware that skimps on this - Providing the data rate, but not being able to drive power-hundry devices such as hard-drives (For example, if connecting a harddrive to my tablet, I need to use a USB hub as a power injector).

The fact that your drive spins down during, or shortly after activity makes it sound like it is barely getting what it needs. To see if this is the case, Try to connect it via a USB hub that has its own powersupply. If you do this, the USB hub will supply the power instead of your computer.

---

**EDIT:** I'm not sure about the 2007 model of Mac Mini, but that sounds very early for USB3 to me. Does it have a USB3 port, or are you running the drive on USB2? If the latter, then that might be the issue, and the USB hub trick is your best bet. While USB3 is backwards compatible, some USB3 devices need more current than a USB2 system can provide, as USB2 is limited to (if my memory serves me right) 400mA.

Comment: Yeah, you're right! This model doesn't have USB3. Your explanation about the disk being power-hungry seems to make sense but what I find weird is the fact that I have no problem when the disk is not in PM mode... I think that there should be errors due to the disk constantly spinning. I only set these hdparm options because I noticed the absence of spindown and up to this moment, nothing wrong happened!